# How can I make my OpenGL camera turn 360 degrees

Tags: c++, opengl, camera

I'm currently working on my entity movement but I've noticed the camera only has a ~180 degree "view", and won't turn past this position. Trying to turn after it's threshold or whatever, will turn the camera really slow and it takes a long time to return. I'd like to be able to turn around the world 360 degrees. Is this possible? I have a short gif to demonstrate

Towards the end of the gif it's clear that the movement begins to slow down and come to a stop.

If someone could help me with the math behind this, or why this is happening it would be greatly appreciated. I've looked around online and can't find anything related.

```
    case GLUT_KEY_LEFT:
        base->camera->angle += 3.0f;
        break;

    case GLUT_KEY_RIGHT:
        base->camera->angle -= 3.0f;

        break;


camera->lookat->z = sin(camera->angle);
camera->lookat->x = cos(camera->angle);


gluLookAt(camera->position->getX(), camera->position->getY(), camera->position->getZ(),
            camera->lookat->getX(), camera->lookat->getY(), camera->lookat->getZ(),
            camera->up->getX(), camera->up->getY(), camera->up->getZ());//camera
```

Comment: How are you turning the camera?

Comment: Is your camera position at (0,0,0)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your look-at calculation needs to take the camera's position into account.

Since you're trying to make the camera swivel around its position, you need:

```
camera->lookat->z = camera->position->getZ() + sin(camera->angle);
camera->lookat->x = camera->position->getX() + cos(camera->angle);
```

Comment: This works perfectly, thank you so much! Would it be the same concept for turning the camera up and down also, except on different axis?

Comment: Yes. Your original code was making the camera aim at a point moving in a circle, somewhere away from the camera. It's like looking at a dog running in circles somewhere across the room--you can watch the dog the whole time without looking behind you. What you really wanted was for the dog to run in circles around you, and to turn to follow it.

Comment: I get it now thanks! As sin and cos are used for the z and x axis, would tan be used for the y for looking up and down?

Comment: Sorry, no, it's just the principle of taking the camera's position into account that still applies. When you rotate around a single axis, it's pretty simple to calculate what it means to add a rotation to the left or right, just by keeping track of a single angle. Full three-dimensional rotation is a much more complicated topic.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use trigonometry, and you need to change the x coordinate you look at as well. Take a look at the [unit circle](http://etc.usf.edu/clipart/43200/43210/unit-circle2_43210_lg.gif). As you increase or decrease your x coordinate, you get closer and closer to the line x = 0. To actually look behind you, you need to change the y coordinate that you look at.

So in OpenGL, this means keeping an angle which is the direction you're looking in. In your event loop you would update it:

```
case GLUT_KEY_LEFT:
    camera->angle_look_at -= 5; // 5 is a totally random value.
                        // You can choose something more appropriate
    break;

case GLUT_KEY_RIGHT:
    camera->angle_look_at += 5;
    break;
```

When you call gluLookAt, you should use this angle to generate the coordinates you look at.

```
x = sin(camera->angle_look_at);
y = 0; // Or any other number.
z = cos(camera->angle_look_at);
gluLookAt(..., x, y, z, ...);
```

Once you start looking up and down you can use the same approach, by keeping an angle for the vertical as well.

Comment: That didn't seem to work. Should I be changing the gluLookAt function? When I tried setting the direction in the game loop it was trying to move but then setting itself back.  http://i.gyazo.com/ed09fa47ad0929077cdd9e471657d3ca.gif

Comment: If camera->lookat->z and x are passed to gluLookAt then you should be fine. Is the angle variable being reset somewhere? It should probably be a member of your camera class, as it needs to be kept.

Comment: Yeah it's a member of my Camera class, I don't think it's resetting. Is the problem with the sin(angle)? Because I've printed out the values and they never go above 1. I've edited my post to show my code now

Comment: No, that's how it's supposed to work. Take another look at the unit circle. Your camera is the center of that circle. As you rotate around that circle, the coordinates you look at change. When the angle is 0, your x value is 1 and your y value is 0. As the angle increases, your x value decreases and your y value increases. Once the angle is 90 degrees, x = 0 and y = 1. Then things change. x continues to decrease, but y stops increasing and decreases instead. sin and cos are the functions for the x and y ordinates. The important thing to remember is that these functions aren't linear.

Comment: How would this affect the Z axis though? I'm only looking to rotate around one axis at the moment, being the Z so I can have the effect of spinning 360 degrees

Comment: Rotation needs two axis.

Comment: You're rotating around the Y axis. To achieve this you need to change the x and z ordinates for where you look. Draw a circle on a piece of paper if you don't believe me. If you change only the z ordinate, you won't be able to look behind you, no matter how much you try.

Comment: Apologies, I'm still learning but have took everything into consideration. So how would I determine when I would need to alter the z and x coordinate? Every 90 degrees?

Comment: No, you should calculate it every time you change where the camera is pointing.